# Исключить внутренние контуры

Tags: c++, opencv

В opencv с помощью `findContours(threshold_output, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE, Point(0, 0));` нахожу контуры.

Так, у буквы `О` — два контура, и внутренний контур закрашивается.

Как исключить внешние контуры у замкнутых фигур, при этом сохранив размеры фигуры?

```
vector<vector<Point> > contours;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
Mat threshold_output = getBinaryImage(src_gray);    
findContours(threshold_output, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE, Point(0, 0));
vector<vector<Point> > contours_poly(contours.size());
vector<Rect> boundRect(contours.size());
vector<Point2f>center(contours.size());
vector<float>radius(contours.size());
cout << "contours.size()" << contours.size();
for (size_t i = 1; i < contours.size(); i++)
{
    approxPolyDP(Mat(contours[i]), contours_poly[i], 1, true);
    boundRect[i] = boundingRect(Mat(contours_poly[i]));
}

Mat drawing(threshold_output.size(), CV_8UC3, Scalar(255, 255, 255));
```

Если использовать `CV_RETR_EXTERNAL`, то самый внешний контур, который по границе картинки, будет первым и последним. Если не закрашивать контуры, тогда буква `о` будет между двумя контурами пустая.
Ну или найти один общий контур, кроме контура картинки.

Comment: Может просто отрезать края у картинки, чтобы не было «внешнего» контура?

Comment: Что такое "контур картинки"?

Answer (score 1):

Судя по

> Если использовать CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, то самый внешний контур,
>   который по границе картинки, будет первым и последним.

... выходит, что фон на исходном изображении не чёрный. Это неправильно. Функция `findContours()` (как и многие другие в OpenCV) хардкорно ориентирована на то, что фон на бинарном изображении должен иметь абсолютно чёрный цвет (значение, равное `0`), а объект или объекты - другой цвет (любое значение от `1` и вплоть до `255` включительно). Обычно используют пару: `0` и `255`.

Для того, чтобы инвертировать матрицу, допустим, сделать чёрную букву "o" на белом фоне в белую букву на чёрном фоне, можно применить простую операцию:

```
// Исходное изображение: чёрная буква на белом фоне.
cv::Mat src_mat = ...;

// А здесь получится белая буква на чёрном фоне,
// т.е. то, что надо для использования в findContours().
cv::Mat inv_mat = ~src_mat;
```

Бинарное изображение в OpenCV - это по большей части условность, т.к. всё равно используется тип `unsigned char`. Фактически, это изображение в оттенках серого, а уж каково реальное значение пикселей - `0-1`, `0-255` или ещё какое - это отдано на откуп программисту. Поэтому, загрузив картинку из файла, имеет смысл её бинаризовать принудительно, поскольку часто трудно гарантировать "на глаз", что изображение содержит требуемые значения, и  вместо `0` в отдельном пикселе не записано, скажем, значение `1`.

Для бинаризации в OpenCV можно использовать функцию `threshold()`. Она имеет множество параметров, подробнейшим образом описанных (в т.ч. с картинками) в документации, поэтому останавливаться на ней подробно, вероятно, смысла нет. Отмечу лишь, что предыдущий мой пример с инвертированием значений матрицы может быть реализован также и с помощью обозначенной функции, плюс, собственно, бинаризация. Так сказать, два зайца одним выстрелом.